# Pandas - How to keep rows in a Dataframe that are different when comparing with another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my question is:
I have two Dataframes:

**Dataframe 1:**

[image: dataframe 1]

**Dataframe 2:**

[image: Dataframe 2]

If you notice, Dataframe 2 has some updated values and I want to create a new Dataframe that has only theses updated values, no matter which column had its updated value.

**Desired Dataframe:**

[image: Desired Dataframe]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question to show your sample input and expected output in the body of your question, not as an image, and please show code for what you've tried based on your own research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work, I came with a solution. I don't know if it is the best way to do it:

This is Dataframe 1:

```
In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
    id ColA  ColB    ColC
0   4  AAA     5  Test 1
1   7  BBB     4  Test 2
2  49  CCC     7  Test 3
3  71  DDD     9  Test 4
4  84  EEE    11  Test 5
```

And this is Dataframe 2:

```
In [5]: df2
Out[5]: 
Out[5]: 
    id   ColA  ColB    ColC
0    4  AAAAA     5  Test 1
1    7    BBB    38  Test 2
2   49    CCC     7  Test 3
3   71  DDDDD   104  Test 4
4   84    EEE    11  Test_5
5  102    FFF    23  Test 6
```

So, I want to create a new Dataframe that only has items that exists only in Dataframe 2:

```
In [6]: df_unique = df2[~df2.id.isin(df1.id)]
In [7]: df_unique
Out[7]: 
    id ColA  ColB    ColC
5  102  FFF    23  Test 6
```

And then I remove these items from Dataframe 2 so that it has only the items that were modified:

```
In [8]: df2 = df2[~df2.id.isin(df_unique.id)]
In [9]: df2
Out[9]: 
   id   ColA  ColB    ColC
0   4  AAAAA     5  Test 1
1   7    BBB    38  Test 2
2  49    CCC     7  Test 3
3  71  DDDDD   104  Test 4
4  84    EEE    11  Test_5
```

Finally, I create a new Dataframe that only has the items modified compared to Dataframe 1:

```
In [10]: df_merged = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='outer', 
                     indicator=True).query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1)
In [11]: df_merged
Out[11]: 
   id   ColA  ColB    ColC
0   4  AAAAA     5  Test 1
1   7    BBB    38  Test 2
3  71  DDDDD   104  Test 4
4  84    EEE    11  Test_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make sure we have the right dataframes:

```
In [270]: df1
Out[270]:
     a   b
0  aaa   5
1  bbb   4
2  ccc   7
3  ddd   9
4  eee  11

In [271]: df2
Out[271]:
       a    b
0  aaaaa    5
1    bbb   38
2    ccc    7
3  ddddd  104
4    eee   11
```

We want `df2`'s values, so left join:

```
In [272]: df = df2.set_index('a').join(df1.set_index('a'), how='left', rsuffix="_r")

In [273]: df
Out[273]:
         b   b_r
a
aaaaa    5   NaN
bbb     38   4.0
ccc      7   7.0
ddddd  104   NaN
eee     11  11.0
```

We only care about when the values differ:

```
In [274]: df = df[df.b != df.b_r]

In [275]: df
Out[275]:
         b  b_r
a
aaaaa    5  NaN
bbb     38  4.0
ddddd  104  NaN
```

We no longer need `df1`'s values:

```
In [276]: df = df.drop(columns=['b_r'])
In [277]: df
Out[277]:
         b
a
aaaaa    5
bbb     38
ddddd  104
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in old df rows whose id is not in the new one, concat vertically the two dataframes.

```
df_old = df_old[~df_old.id.isin(df_new.id)]
df_result = pd.concat((df_old, df_new), ignore_index=True)
```

I assumed that your field ID is different than the pandas id, if not, don't ignore the index.
Didn't test but should do the trick.